# Communicating with PuTTY via pipe

Tags: c++, c, ssh, pipe, putty

I want to capture PuTTY's STDIN and STDOUT pipes. So I open `putty.exe` via **CreateProcess** with passing created pipes but I can't read anything from pipes. My code works when I run a bat file.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

```
//This code is from MSDN and I edited it a little
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#define BUFSIZE 4096

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void);
void WriteToPipe(void);
void ReadFromPipe(void);
void ErrorExit(PTSTR);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited.
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) )
        ErrorExit((PTSTR)TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
        ErrorExit((PTSTR)TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN.
    if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit((PTSTR)TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited.
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
        ErrorExit((PTSTR)TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create the child process: putty
    CreateChildProcess();

    // read from pipe and printf incoming data
    ReadFromPipe();
}

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT.
// Stop when there is no more data.
void ReadFromPipe(void)
{
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

   for (;;)
   {
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 )
          break;

      printf("received hex:\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < dwRead; i++)
      {
          printf("%02X", chBuf[i]);
      }
      printf("\nactual string: %s\n",chBuf);
   }
}

void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
    ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure.
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process.

    bSuccess = CreateProcess(L"E:\\putty.exe",
                            NULL,          // command line
                            NULL,          // process security attributes
                            NULL,          // primary thread security attributes
                            TRUE,          // handles are inherited
                            0,             // creation flags
                            NULL,          // use parent's environment
                            NULL,          // use parent's current directory
                            &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer
                            &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION

   // If an error occurs, exit the application.
   if ( ! bSuccess )
      ErrorExit((PTSTR)TEXT("CreateProcess"));
   else
   {
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example.

      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
   }
}

// Format a readable error message, display a message box,
// and exit from the application.
void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that PuTTY doesn't have pipe for this purpose and since I didn't want to use plink, I modified PuTTY's source code and embedded pipe in it. Now it works as I want.

Comment: So you have effectively implemented Plink. Why?

Comment: Well putty is not the same as plink. Since customer will use my application, I couldn't restrict user to use plink. Instead customer will be able to use rich putty with my pipe communication and everything will be good.

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY is a GUI application. You cannot communicate with it using input/output redirection.

Use [`plink.exe` from PuTTY package](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's a console application with the same set of command-line arguments and features as PuTTY.

Though even better, using some C++ SSH library instead.